# properties of limit inferior

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following property:

> If $x_n \le y_n$ for every $n\ge n_0$, then
>   $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n$$

I'm lost on that. Please, could you give me any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$\liminf_n x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl(\inf_{k\ge n}x_k\Bigr)=\lim_{\substack{n\to\infty\\ n\ge n_0}}\Bigl(\inf_{k\ge n}x_k\Bigr)$$ 
by definition.
Now if $ x_n\ge y_n$ for all $n\ge n_0$, there follows that $\;\displaystyle\inf_{k\ge n}x_k\ge\inf_{k\ge n}y_k$ for all $n\ge n_0$, so that this inequality is preserved when passing to the limit.